# New unity input system - is there a way to not execute an action if a modifier is being pressed?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I want 2 different things to happen for when SHIFT+Q is pressed and when merely 'q' is pressed.

Currently when I press SHIFT+Q both actions are being fired, and I don't want that. Is there a way to do this elegantly in the action mapping? I would prefer not to have to hardcode keys in my scripts, but if that's the only way then I will just check in script if shift is currently engaged. It will be a giant headache in the future though if I want to allow players to edit key mappings.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone coming across this in the future - It looks like this feature is being implemented in InputSystem 1.4.0+

(ChangeLog: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem/blob/develop/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem/CHANGELOG.md)

From the changelog:

> Added support for keyboard shortcuts and mutually exclusive use of modifiers.
> In short, this means that a "Shift+B" binding can now prevent a "B" binding from triggering.

Just need to pick one of the new 'OneModifierComposite' or 'TwoModifierComposite'.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in [1.4.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/changelog/CHANGELOG.html) and then adjusted further in [1.4.4](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.4/changelog/CHANGELOG.html)

To make it work now, just add the two actions with two bindings (one with just [Q}, the other with [Shift + Q]). Then go to Project *Settings > Input System Package* and create the settings asset (click the only button). Then scroll down and check 'enable input consumption'

This will make the more complex binding [SHIFT + Q] consume keypress, so the less complex binding [Q] will not be triggered. Keep in mind that this consumption also happens across different action maps.

Answer (score 1):

Consumption enable is necessary in Project Settings > Input System Package

[Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XkmH.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit: please scroll to the bottom of this post. It turns out there’s actually a way to do this natively**

I’m not totally sure, but one thing that I know will for sure work is to have separate actions mapped to shift and to q. Then in your OnShift function, simply set a “shiftIsPressed” flag to true or false, depending on whether the context is starting or ending. Then your your OnQ function can look something like this:

```
void OnQ(CallbackContext ctx)
{
    if(!ctx.actionStarted) return;
    if(shiftPressed) ShiftQ();
    else Q();
}
```

This will keep key remapping open to you. It’s not perfect, if the player remaps Q to, say R, it will also remap ShiftQ to ShiftR. Without knowing more about your application though, that sounds like a good thing.

**Edit:**

To get Shift+Q to register as a separate action from Q, all you need to do is click the plus button on your ShiftQ action and select “Button With One Modifier Composite”. Then set Shift as the modifier and Q as the button. If you want to rebind Shift+Q to, say R, then set the button to R and the modifier to “Any Button”.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I would like the player to be able to edit the key mappings independently if possible. SHIFT+Q and Q are 2 totally unrelated actions in the game. For now I have done what you suggested though and just have a flag for keeping track of when shift is engaged. I'm a little worried about somehow getting into a state where the program misses a shift cancel for whatever reason and the program thinks the shift key is stuck, but I guess that's pretty unlikely.

Comment: Sure! I’ve had a chance to try this out with the new input system and it turns out there actually is native support for what you’re looking for. I’ll edit my post with that

Comment: I appreciate you looking into this. What you described in your edit is the same way I had it originally before I made the OP. My issue is that when pressing SHIFT-Q both the action for SHIFT-Q as well as the action for Q are triggered. Did you also have a mapping for Q as well as SHIFT-Q? And if so did both trigger when you pressed SHIFT-Q?